# IIS and tomcat site

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, tomcat

Im new at IIS 7.5, so my I need some help.

I have tomcat web server at my server, on this tomcat i have working app which is available at  http://my_domain_name.com:8008/some_war. Due to a lot of reasons this path `/some_war`cannot be changed (hard code etc).

I have IIS at my server too. I play with HTTP redirection and URL rewrite but they are didnt solve me issue.

I want do next: when people site:`http://my_domain_name.com` the must see site from  http://my_domain_name.com:8008/some_war (url in browser must not change, as in case of HTTP redirection).

Can you please help me or advice something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse pass in your VirtualHost entry for my_domain_name.com. Syntax goes like this

ProxyPass / http://my_domain_name.com:8080/some_war 
ProxyPassReverse / http://my_domain_name.com:8080/some_war